# Google Drive Realtime API: registerReference method on CollaborativeString

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm using the Google Drive Realtime API to share a CollaborativeString between the users of my application. I'd like to share the caret position of a user with all the other ones, but it seems that the `registerReference` method is not defined for CollaborativeString (though it is stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.CollaborativeString#gapi.drive.realtime.CollaborativeString.prototype.registerReference)).

In the Realtime Playground app, I do not see any reference to the `registerReference` method in the code, the only hint are these lines in [rtpg.string.js](https://github.com/googledrive/realtime-playground/blob/master/js/rtpg.string.js):

```
rtpg.string.connectUi = function() {
  $(rtpg.string.INPUT_SELECTOR).keyup(rtpg.string.onInput);
  $(rtpg.string.INPUT_SELECTOR).click(rtpg.string.updateReference);
  $(rtpg.string.INPUT_SELECTOR).keyup(rtpg.string.updateReference);
};
```

the last two lines make reference to an `updateReference` method, which in turn is not present in the code.
Did I miss something?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo - I just confirmed that registerReference is available on CollaborativeString objects created through the Realtime API. You can see it both in the prototype (gapi.drive.realtime.CollaborativeString.prototype.registerReference) as well as when you instantiate a new string (doc.getModel().createString().registerReference). Not sure what those calls to updateReference are though. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @GrantWatters for your reply! Just to check if I'm doing things right: I initialize the Model with `model.getRoot().set("text",model.createString("This is a Realtime API test!"));`. So, should I be able to write `doc.getModel().getRoot().get("text").registerReference(0,false)`?

Comment: Looks right to me! Is that not working?

Comment: I get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` if I try to call any method on `doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text')` (say, `doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text').insertString(0,'TEST')`). One thing that looks suspicious to me is that `console.log(doc.getModel().getRoot().get('text'))` prints the bare content of the string - no hints it is a collaborative object.

Comment: I'd give something like 'doc.getModel().createString("test").registerReference(0, false)' a shot and see how that turns out and work backward from there - I verified that this runs fine for me. If you're creating the CollaborativeString properly you will see an object and not just a plain string. As a sidenote - giving yourself access to the document/model as a global in the console makes iterating and experimenting much easier.

Comment: Ouch, I just discovered the cause of my problem. I create the model correctly, but I update it the wrong way (i.e. by doing `doc.getModel().getRoot().set("text", newText)` instead of `doc.getModel().getRoot().get("text").setText(newText);`). Sorry! :(

Comment: Glad you figured it out even if it's just a small coding mistake!